# Java Formatter: old formatted values are kept

Tags: java, formatter

I use the following formatter:

```
protected static final ThreadLocal<Formatter> textFormatter = new ThreadLocal<Formatter>() {
    @Override
    protected Formatter initialValue() {
        return new Formatter();
    }
};
```

I use this formatter in one method:

```
final String firstValue = textFormatter.get().format("%s and %s", "a","b");
final String secondValue = textFormatter.get().format("%s and %s", "c","d");
```

I expect firstValue to be "a and b" and secondValue="c and d" but secondValue="a and bc and d". So  the old value is kept and it's also appended to secondValue. Is there a way to clear the formatter?

Comment: As far as I know, java.util.Formatter are not meant for reuse. You better off instantiating two different formatters instead of just one. Also, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107539/is-there-a-way-to-re-use-a-formatter-object-within-a-loop

Answer (score 1):

By default Formatter uses a StringBuilder to keep the result of format.
You can erase old formatted values by erasing the StringBuilder:

```java
StringBuilder out = (StringBuilder) textFormatter.get().out();
final String firstValue = textFormatter.get().format("%s and %s", "a","b");
out.delete(0, out.length());
final String secondValue = textFormatter.get().format("%s and %s", "c","d");
out.delete(0, out.length());
```

Answer (score -1):

initialValue() is called only once per thread when you call get()

So that mean you are getting only one Formatter object in both lines above

and since Formatter.format method Writes a formatted string to the Formatter object's destination (internal buffer in Formatter method)

then since you are making it equal String java will auto call toString() on the formatter.

So first time the toString will write the buffer contents which is the correct content  "a and b"

but second time it will write the full buffer since you didnt flush the buffer "a and bc and d"

the fix is easy

```
final String firstValue = textFormatter.get().format("%s and %s", "a","b");
textFormatter.get().flush();
final String secondValue = textFormatter.get().format("%s and %s", "c","d");
textFormatter.get().flush();
```

Comment: this is wrong. old formatted values are still kept.